# Possible combinations to form a playing eleven out of 15 players in which one unknown player is injured?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

### Question

There are 15 players in a squad out of which 11 are to be chosen for the playing-eleven. Out of the 15, one of the players is injured and we don't know who it is. Find the total number of teams which can be formed?

### Approach

Let the players be labelled from 1 to 15.

*Case 1:* 1 is injured.
We are left with 14 players out of which 11 are to be chosen, i.e $14 \choose 11$

*Case n*: Proceeding in the same way, we have $15 \cdot {14 \choose 11}$ possible combinations.

### Doubt

Obviously, $15 \cdot {14 \choose 11}$ is *not* the answer as we have some repetition. But I am unable eliminate those repetitions to get to an answer. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: There are $14 \choose 11$ options no matter which player is injured. There's no need to multiply with $15$ since only one player is injured at a time.

Comment: @AndreasLenz , but what if we don't know who is injured? All possible combinations in every case where each one of the player has an equal chance to be found injured?

Comment: We may not know which player is injured, but we know that there are only ${ 14 \choose 11 }$ teams which do not contain an injured player. (Presumably the team cannot include an injured player, else there are $15 \choose 11$ possible teams.)

Comment: @CalvinLin , so if we include all combinations where one player is injured (selecting the injured player too) , we get $15 \choose 11$ as the answer?

Comment: Can you prove that?

Comment: @CalvinLin , $15 \choose 11$ contains all possible team selections. Each selection occurs in  four other sets( in which there is condition that one player is injured). Therefore, $15 \choose 11$ is the answer. Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Each selection occurs in four other sets( in which there is condition that one player is injured)"? I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Each selection contains 11 players. Four players are not there (say 3 be such a player in a particular set) per set. Now, that particular selection also occurs in the set having condition that 3 is injured. @CalvinLin